# Post Object to an URL in Java, Spring

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, cxf

I guess am missing out something

I have a CXF Service like

```
@POST
@Path("/verify")
@Produces({ "application/xml", "application/json" })
public Response getSmartAlertResults(
        UserDetails usrDetails);
```

UserDetails is a Java class with just two fields username and password. How do I post data to it from code. or putting it simply form another java application I need to post UserDetails object. Its going to be a console app. The service is not being called properly.

What I Did?

```
         URL url = new URL("http://localhost/verify");

         HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)
         url.openConnection();
         conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
         conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
         conn.setDoOutput(true);

         OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

         ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
         oos.writeObject("usrDetails");
         // this is the object to pass
                     oos.writeObject(userDetails);

         System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/post.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use weblclient provided by CXF. Since you are using json make sure your json provider is configured properly

```
try {
            String endPointURL = "your url";
            WebClient client = null;


            client = WebClient.create(endPointURL);

            client.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

            MyObject obj =new MyObject();

            response = client.post(obj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```